# What are the most common symbols or words used to refer a reader to a glossary?

Tags: symbols

What are the most common symbols or words used after difficult words in a text to refer a reader to a glossary for a definition?

Comment: I've mostly seen: *, #, ▫.

Comment: You can put a * symbol in front of the word and at the end of the text mention a note that : * Please refer glossary for definition

Comment: Hugely related question: [Footnote symbol sequence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62535/historical-reasons-of-footnotes-sequence-symbols)

Comment: You can put a * symbol in front of the word and at the end of the text mention a note that : * Please refer glossary for definition

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people using

Superscript [1], [2]...if there is more than one, and the information can be in the footnote or glossary.

Or parenthesis (refer to glossary)